# Confusion about the conferment of A.S instead of R.A on the Sahaba Ali?

Tags: sahaba, ali

Assalamu Alaikum,
Please, is A.S. instead of R.A. conferred on Ali? My understanding is A.S. is for Prophets and R.A. is for the Companions and the Tabi'in.

Answer (score 1):

"A.S" -> "Alayh es Salam" علیه السلام
means salam to him.

"R.A" -> "RaziaAllah o Anh"  رضی الله عنه
means God be satisfied of him.

All Muslims use "A.S" for all prophets and use "pbuh" for holy prophet Mohammad.
Also Shia Muslims use "A.S" their 12 Imams after holy prophet include Imam Ali.
Sunni Muslims use "R.A" for 3 khalifas after holy prophet and use "A.S" for 4th of them, Imam Ali, because "Ali bn AbiTaleb" was only sahaba of holy prophet who never pray anything expect Allah, before Islam.

Comment: No, afaik they use karam-ulallaho-wajhu, not Alayh es Salam. And please avoid adding salutations like salam on alaykom in posts.

Comment: This is also an oversimplification. This is by no means done by all or even most Sunnis. Indeed some of the Sunni scholars consider it wrong to use this honorific for anyone other than the Prophets and angels. Also keep in mind that there are Sahaba who were born in Islam to Muslim parents (i.e. children of the Sahaba) and hence never committed shirk so this reasoning is fallacious.

Answer (score 0):

We sunni muslims don’t use "A.S" for Ali R.A. We only use them for Prophets except Mohammad SAW. Get your facts straight.

Comment: This is an oversimplification. For example some hadith scholars like Bukhari have used عليه السلام for the Ahl al-Bayt like Fatimah, Umm Kulthum, Hassan and Hussain and even Abbas and Ali. This is either their own act or that of the Sahaba and Tabieen from whom they narrates. There are numerous examples of it, [this](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5361) is just one.